# Can I use programs using OpenGL and GLUT in Raspberry Pi 3b+?

Tags: opengl, raspberry-pi, glut

I have a ready-made program code that uses OpenGL and glut, can I compile and run this program in Rasbian on Raspberry 3b+?

Comment: [Possibly](https://github.com/anholt/mesa/wiki/VC4-OpenGL-support).

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, but with a caveat

You *can* use OpenGL software on RPis, but you need to note that RPIs do not implement up to the newest standard, `4.6`. I think they implement up to version OpenGL `2.0` ES, but don't quote me on that.

If you want to find out, you can simply enable the GL driver in `raspi-config` and then run the command

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

to figure out what standard you can use.
This will determine what standard of OpenGL code works and therefore what code will compile.

Only after you verify the version will you know if the code will run.

Even then, there is sooo little RAM that it may not work.
That is outside the scope of this question though.